# How do I print each line of a text file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Only the last line gets displayed to the console when I try:

```
File.open("test.txt").each do |line|;
  puts line
end
```

the text file is:

```
123
456
789
```

only 789 get printed to the console. Could this be an issue with my terminal? I've tried new windows, same results.

Comment: Are you sure your code is exactly that? Could I ask which version of ruby you're using?

Answer (score 2):

Turned out to be an issue with the file being read. I made a new file with same contents and it worked fine. Interestingly, the original file would display nothing with 'cat'. What's also odd is they both have the same contents and permissions. I'm baffled.

Good catch with the semicolon though! Surprisingly it still works with it, running ruby 2.3.1p112.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed. That's why I asked about the version and the code :)